# Reference Error array is not defined

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I tried the following code to retrieve values from the database and store them in a javascript array using php array. I tried using the following code, But it is returning me a Reference Error array is not defined.The code is as follows.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("cerebra", $con);
$sql="select name from details order by download desc limit 20";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
$query=mysql_query($sql,$con);
$names=array();
$index=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $names[$index]=$row[0];
    $index++;
}
?>
<script>
var comp=new array();
<?php
 $i=0;
 foreach($names as $a){
        $i++;
        echo "comp[$i]='".$a."';\n";

        }
?>
for(i=0;i<comp.length;i++)
            alert(comp[i]);

</script>
```

Comment: An possibly unrelated note: there's no need for `$index` in your `while` loop you may as well use `$names[] = $row[0]`.

Comment: Your browser's developer tools will be able to point you to what exactly is not defined; then you will have to determine why and fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `var comp = new Array()` not `array()`. Skip that anyhow and use `var comp = []` right away.

Comment: but the first value am getting is undefined. How come?

Comment: See why you get issues with undefined in you Javascript in my updated answer.

Comment: yes stupid me...sorry..i placed the increment there to debug the code. And that ended up giving me an error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. Here is a much better way of going about it:

```
<?php
  $phpArray = array("foo", "bar", "baz");
  //....
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var jsArray = <? echo json_encode($phpArray); ?>;
</script>
```

Taken from here: [How to use an array value from php to javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180133/how-to-use-an-array-value-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why do you run your query twice?

```
...

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
$query=mysql_query($sql,$con);

...
```

Second in Javascript the array object is called `Array`, not `array`.
So try with

```
var comp = new Array();
```

**Update:**

> but the first value am getting is undefined. How come? – user2129868

Because you increment `$i` before getting the value. So `$i` is `1` and not `0` on your first iteration in your Javascript.

So change

```
<script>
var comp=new array();
<?php
 $i=0;
 foreach($names as $a){
        $i++;
        echo "comp[$i]='".$a."';\n";

        }
?>
for(i=0;i<comp.length;i++)
            alert(comp[i]);

</script>
```

to

```
<script>
var comp=new array();
<?php
 $i=0;
 foreach($names as $a){
        echo "comp[".$i++."]='".$a."';\n";
        }
?>
for(i=0;i<comp.length;i++)
            alert(comp[i]);

</script>
```

Otherwise when you try to fetch the elements with

```
for(i=0;i<comp.length;i++)
            alert(comp[i]);
```

`0` will be undefined since `1`was the first index you added.

Answer (score 1):

```
new array();
```

should be

```
new Array();
```

in your javascript.

EDIT: you should also stop using mysql_* functions.