# How to pass php array to another js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have index.php file where i have a php array like this,

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

and i want the $arr value in jquery function which is in another file named fetchvalue.js,

```
$(function  ()  {
    $('#barchart').sparkline(ARRAYFROMPHP, {
        type: 'bar', 
        barColor: '#3B5998',    
        height:'35px',
        weight:'96px'
    });
});
```

Please help me out in this. I am new to php and JS.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `.sparkline` do?

Comment: You'll have to print the array, so you van use it in javascript. Take a look at this answer: [How to use an array value from php to javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2180190/1608705)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use an array value from php to javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180133/how-to-use-an-array-value-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: @pattle .sparkline is piechart where the values in the array is used to draw them.

Comment: @annemartijn the link you shared is for php and JS in same where i have asked for php and js in different files. thanks

Comment: A more specific duplicate would be: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2928844/1608705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass your PHP array to JS.

```
echo '<script>var arrayFromPhp = ' . json_encode($arr) . ';</script>';
```

after that you can access the array in your JS file in the variable `arrayFromPhp`.

Not that JS doesnt have associative arrays so your example would be an object.

Answer (score 2):

As you use jquery library , you can use `$.getJSON()` ( or $.ajax , or other method)

```
var ARRAYFROMPHP = [];
$.getJSON('index.php', function(data){
 ARRAYFROMPHP = data;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Call your url that gives you the json array and then trigger sparklines like this..

```
$(function  ()  {
    $.getJSON('your_url_for_json',{},function(response) 
    {           
        $('#barchart').sparkline(response, {
                type: 'bar', 
               barColor: '#3B5998',    
               height:'35px',
               weight:'96px'
           });  

    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON string directly in js:

```
console.log(ARRAYFROMPHP['a']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply can you please explain me in little detail how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Php is server side language while JS is client side. You cannot make talk to each other directly. Use some sort of web service or Ajax to interact.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'Call URL',
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
    //Date will be your JSON returned from the PHP.
    alert(data)
}
});
```